# Help on Embossing Letters Need a Larger Effect

Tags: rendering, node-editor, uv-image-editor, displacement, normal-map

I am trying to recreate this emboss effect:

[image]

I've tried doing so through displacement nodes and I'm not seeing a good result. I've rendered two images with different approaches and still looks the same

[image]
[image]
[image]

Some existing answers are outdated and not specific.

Comment: While blender has evolved and changed as a software package, the workflows have not changed much. You came here to ask the community for help. How is that you can demand that the community give you specific answers? *Have you tried any of the older workflows before asking your question?* If the duplicates do not answer your question, then [edit] this one and *clearly* explain how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just posting this so I can post the pic. This is just an example of how you should set up your nodes. I used a multiply on the MixRGB node because I often transfer dark ridges this way, but I don't know what your image looks like, so I can't tell what the values are doing. If you need the lights, use Lighten or Add. Or disregard all of that, and use whatever looks best. The main point is that you must convert the sRGB image into black and white before introducing to the Bump Node.

[image: Connections]

I didn't show it here, but I also often mix the procedural component of my textures heavily with white (or black sometime depending on the need) using another MixRGB node to easily soften the contrast (strength) before mixing it with the others. I find the default values are often too strong, and look unrealistic.

Comment: Thanks, It was the same effect but its okay.